# SQL Server Update Column based on SQL stored in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 SQL tables with the one table containing source and destination columns and another table containing a transformation logic for the source values. I would need to apply the transformation logic and update the destination column.

Table1

```
ID | PreVal |PostVal
1  |   5    | 
1  |   6    | 
1  |   7    | 
2  |   10   | 
2  |   15   |
```

Table2 - Transformation Logic

```
ID | Logic
1  |   case when PreVal < 6 then 1 else 0 end
2  |   case when PreVal < 12 then 1 else 0 end
```

Is it possible to have just a common update statement by joining both tables (instead of building dynamic SQL by going through each ID in a cursor) to achieve the below output

```
ID | PreVal |PostVal
1  |   5    | 1
1  |   6    | 0
1  |   7    | 0
2  |   10   | 1
2  |   15   | 0
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: _Is it possible to have just a common update statement by joining both tables (instead of building dynamic SQL by going through each ID in a cursor) to achieve the below output_ No, you'll need to use dynamic sql for this.

Comment: If you change your logic table data so it just has the value of PreVal that the first table's value has to be less than, then yes. But you can't do what you want with the transformation table as is.

Comment: @Tanner I do not mind a dynamic SQL, but I do not want to go through ID by ID in a cursor given that this table leverages columnstore index.

Comment: How many rows are in table1 and table2? I suppose table2 has more than two rows.

Comment: Your logic is always something like `if id = x then if preVal < y then postVal = 1 else postVal = 0` or could it be `if id = x then if preVal < y then postVal = 1 else postVal = z`?

Comment: Even for Dynamic SQL, this will be a real challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Put your logic into a formal table and then join:

```
UPDATE t1
SET PostVal = CASE WHEN t1.PreVal < t2.PreVal
                   THEN t2.positive ELSE t2.negative END
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 6 AS PreVal, 1 AS positive, 0 AS negative
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 12, 1, 0
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that I have about a million records with almost 1000 transformation logics, and hence the need for a separate 'logic table'

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that :

```
WITH query as
(
    select 1 as id, 6 as 'preval_max', 1 as 'then_result', 0 as 'end_result' union
    select 2 as id, 12 as 'preval_max', 1 as 'then_result', 0 as 'end_result'   
)
UPDATE Table1
SET PostVal = case when Table1.preval < query.preval_max then query.then_result else query.end_result end
FROM Table1
inner join query 
    on Table1.id = query.id
```

Query's columns allow you to have different logic.

Answer (score 0):

If your transformation logic is too complicated like:

```
1 case when PreVal < 6 then 1 else 0 end
2 case when PreVal = 0 then 1 else 2 end
3 case when PreVal > 1000 then 0 else 1 end
4 case when PreVal = 1 then 1 else 2 end
```

then I believe there is nothing you could do.

In that case I would run:

```
select distinct
    'update table1 set PostVal = ' + b.Logic + ' where Id = ' + convert (varchar(10), a.id)
from
    table1 a
    inner join table2 b on ( a.id = b.id )
```

to produce the update statement for each row and run them in segments.